# Host HTML file with direct download link

Tags: html, online-storage

Is there a host where you can upload an HTML file without needing an account and then there is a direct download link?

I would need this for my HTML class, so that students can upload a file and then use tools like these SEO Tests. They all just work with a link. 
If there is an SEO Test tool (Meta Tags, H1, etc.) that works like the W3C validator, where you can upload a file, that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [GitHub's Gist](https://gist.github.com). You can post your HTML files anonymously and get back the raw source code (not parsed) when you visit it.